# Building a Custom Journey Builder Activity that would insert a row in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I am trying to insert a row into a Data Extension when a Contact enters the Custom Journey Builder Activity.

I am trying to insert a row with two attributes: Cohort (which is entered via the custom activity iframe input text field), ContactKey (I am trying to get this using {{Contact.Key}}).

**I am able to get the Cohort value, but not the ContactKey.**

In my index.js file, I've got the following functions.

```
function onInitActivity(payload) {

    // set the activity object from this payload. We'll refer to this object as we
    // modify it before saving.
    activity = payload;

    const hasInArguments = Boolean(
        activity.arguments &&
        activity.arguments.execute &&
        activity.arguments.execute.inArguments &&
        activity.arguments.execute.inArguments.length > 0
    );

    const inArguments = hasInArguments ? activity.arguments.execute.inArguments : {};

    console.log('-------- triggered:onInitActivity({obj}) --------');
    console.log('activity:\n ', JSON.stringify(activity, null, 4));
    console.log('Has In Arguments: ', hasInArguments);
    console.log('inArguments', inArguments);
    console.log('-------------------------------------------------');

    // check if this activity has an incoming argument.
    // this would be set on the server side when the activity executes
    // (take a look at execute() in ./ab-usecase/app.js to see where that happens)
    const cohortnameArgument = inArguments.find((arg) => arg.cohortname);

    console.log('Cohort Name Argument', cohortnameArgument);

    // if a cohort name back argument was set, show the message in the view.
    if (cohortnameArgument) {
        document.getElementById('cohort-name').value = cohortnameArgument.cohortname;
    }

    // if the cohort name back argument doesn't exist the user can set it
    // the cohort name back arg
    // will be set once the journey executes the activity
}

function onDoneButtonClick() {
    // we must set metaData.isConfigured in order to tell JB that
    // this activity is ready for activation
    activity.metaData.isConfigured = true;

    // get the cohort name that the user has set and save it to
    const cohortnameInput = document.getElementById('cohort-name');

    activity.arguments.execute.inArguments = [{
        cohortname: cohortnameInput.value,
        contactKey: "{{Contact.Key}}",
    }];

    // you can set the name that appears below the activity with the name property
    activity.name = `Cohort-${activity.arguments.execute.inArguments[0].cohortname}`;

    console.log('------------ triggering:updateActivity({obj}) ----------------');
    console.log('Sending message back to updateActivity');
    console.log('saving\n', JSON.stringify(activity, null, 4));
    console.log('--------------------------------------------------------------');

    connection.trigger('updateActivity', activity);
}
```

In my app.js file, I then use the inArgument to set the fields on my Data Extension.

```
app.post('/modules/ab-usecase/execute', async function (req, res) {
        console.log('debug: /modules/ab-usecase/execute');
    
        const request = req.body;
    
        console.log("req.body", JSON.stringify(req.body));
    
        // Find the in argument
        function getInArgument(k) {
            if (request && request.inArguments) {
                for (let i = 0; i < request.inArguments.length; i++) {
                    let e = request.inArguments[i];
                    if (k in e) {
                        return e[k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        const clientId = 'x';
        const clientSecret = 'x';
        const accountId = 'x';
        const authEndpoint = 'https://x.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
        const dataExtensionEndpoint = 'x.rest.marketingcloudapis.com//data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:x/rows';
    
        const cohortnameInArgument = getInArgument('cohortname');
        const contactkeyInArgument = getInArgument('contactKey');
        
    
        try {
            // Step 1: Authenticate with Salesforce Marketing Cloud
            const authResponse = await axios.post(authEndpoint, {
                grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
                account_id: accountId
            });
    
            const accessToken = authResponse.data.access_token;
    
            // Step 2: Push data to a Data Extension
            const data = {
                items: [
                    {
                        ContactKey: contactkeyInArgument,
                        Cohort: cohortnameInArgument
                    }
                ],
            };
    
            const dataExtensionResponse = await axios.post(dataExtensionEndpoint, data, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });
    
            console.log('Response Object', JSON.stringify(dataExtensionResponse.data));
    
            return res.status(200).json(dataExtensionResponse.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't help you with the custom activity, but I just need to mention you could have achieved the goal of creating a data extension row easily using `{{Contact.Key}}` in the Update Contact activity in Journey Builder

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak yes, using update contact activity makes sense. However for this use case, we don’t have a single DE that is linked in the data designer to do that. Moreover, it was more of logging the split (for random splits) every time a contact enters the path. Therefore, a contact may appear more than once in this DE

Comment: Are you verifying by running the journey using an actual contact in your testing? As the merge field only works in running the journey.